# Subscript sizing of text in math formulas

Tags: fonts, math-mode, plain-tex

I am using Plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Right now, I have

```
\def\text#1{\hbox{#1}}
```

This works for things like

```
$$A + \text{foo bar}$$.
```

However, not for things like:

```
$$\Sum_{ \text{foo} = a}$$.
```

How do I fix this? In particular, I want `\text` to somehow take into account the size of the current math font.

Comment: @Werner: thanks for fixing the type setting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: I think `\mathchoice` is a TeX command, is it not?

Comment: Whoa, this is how it works under the hood? I.e. there's no global "here is current font size" varaible; but instead, it works by specifying: if in Display style, do this; if in Text style, do this, if in script style, if in scriptscript style do this?

Comment: Correct - did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

There exists an [AMS bundle version](http://ctan.org/pkg/amstex) for Plain TeX, too:

```
\input amstex

$$ \text{foo}^{\text{bar}^{\text{baz}}} $$

\bye
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `\mathchoice`, but it hardcodes roman fonts so if you are using inside e.g italic or smallcaps it will not match the surrounding text (might even be desired).

```
\def\text#1{\mathchoice
  {\hbox{\tenrm #1}}
  {\hbox{\tenrm #1}}
  {\hbox{\sevenrm #1}}
  {\hbox{\fiverm #1}}
}

$$
\text{Abcd}^{\text{Abcd}^{\text{Abcd}}}
\textstyle
\text{Abcd}^{\text{Abcd}^{\text{Abcd}}}
$$
\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

use `\def\text#1{{\rm#1}}`  instead

Answer (score 1):

If your `\text{...}` is used for denoting variables, then perhaps `\text` as provided by `amstex.tex` is not the right choice, as its argument will be typeset in the font current outside the formula.

It's thus probably more sensible to say

```
\input amstex
\define\tvar#1{\text{\it #1}}
```

if you want those snippets typeset in italics independently of the context around the formula. If no spaces in the argument is needed, then

```
\define\tvar#1{\italic{#1}}
```

would be sufficient. (In AMS-TeX, the `\define` command is the analog of `\newcommand` in LaTeX, it won't override an already defined command.)

A Plain only definition for supporting also spaces might be

```
\font\sevenit=cmti7
\scriptfont\itfam=\sevenit
\font\fiveit=cmti5
\scriptscriptfont\itfam=\fiveit
\def\tvar{\bgroup\mathcode`\ ="8000 \catcode`\ =12
  \begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\ }}\tvari}
\def\tvari#1{\it#1\egroup}

$\tvar{Abc deff}$%_{\tvar{Abc deff}}$
```

The argument would still be typeset in math mode. If spaces are not required, then

```
\font\sevenit=cmti7
\scriptfont\itfam=\sevenit
\font\fiveit=cmti5
\scriptscriptfont\itfam=\fiveit
\def\tvar#1{{\it#1}}
```

is sufficient.

For getting Roman text it would be exactly the same, with `\rm` in place of `\it` (the `\scriptfont` and `\scriptscriptfont` are already defined).